# Why is it ElasticSearch is not allowed to run as root?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm deploying ElasticSearch inside of a Docker container, which usually run processes as a root user. I get

```
"org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupError: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot run elasticsearch as root"
```

error when trying to start ElasticSearch.

**What's the reason ElasticSearch can't run as root?**

Inside of the docker container, things are isolated and root processes are considered safe. I may be able to configure my image to run as non-root but it requires lots of heavy lifting and is anti-pattern to our deployment model.

I have also tried without docker container but got following error.

./elasticsearch

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: don't run elasticsearch as root.at
```

`org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:93)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:144)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)`

Refer to the log for complete error details.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed a few times already. [Quoting](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/21#issuecomment-297473780) from the Elastic maintained Docker images:

> Elasticsearch has checks that will not allow running it as root. This
>   has been discussed in
>   https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-is-it-elasticsearch-is-not-allowed-to-run-as-root/60413/2
>   and running processes as root inside a docker container is not a best
>   practice. You can see some reasons in the aforementioned discussion,
>   in
>   https://forums.docker.com/t/root-user-or-non-root-user-inside-container/966/10,
>   http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/12/don-run-as-root-inside-of-docker.html
>   and other places. The risks are especially profound for containers
>   like Elasticsearch where users frequently bind mount host directories
>   with write access.

PS: In case you don't want to build your own images, there are officially maintained ones: https://www.docker.elastic.co

Comment: This is one of the stupidest reasons I have read. How about they let me run elasticsearch my way? It's my responsibility, not their!

Comment: Principle of the least privilege is a common best practice. And if you create software that doesn't follow it and "bad stuff" happens because of it, the software creator shares blame in that...

Comment: why would creator share any blame? This makes no sense.